# Replace Mulitple Lines Greedily With BusyBox

Tags: bash, sed, replace, busybox

Given the following input file:

```
text
text
pattern2
pattern3
text
text
pattern1
pattern2
pattern3
pattern2
pattern3
pattern2
pattern3
text
text
```

I need to search for "pattern1" and then I need to replace the first occurrence of "pattern2" and "pattern3" with "pattern2-new" and "pattern3-new" respectively and delete all other occurrences of "pattern2" and "pattern3".  The end result I'm after is:

```
text
text
pattern2
pattern3
text
text
pattern1
pattern2-new
pattern3-new
text
text
```

At first I thought I could do this with sed by selecting a range of lines starting with "pattern1" and ending with "pattern3" and then using the c command to replace the whole range but range selecting in sed is non greedy so that won't work.  However, I could still use sed to do the replacement but then need to figure out another way to delete all other occurrences of "pattern2" and "pattern3" that come after "pattern1".

To complicate things, this is running in a busybox environment so no access to perl or most other fancy tools.  Basically sed, awk, and grep are the only file/string manipulation tools I can think of that busybox supports.

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions:

- we're interested in matching a 'pattern' anywhere in the line, eg, `pattern1` will match where a line = `this is a line with pattern11111`, otherwise additional logic could be added but we'd need a more representative example of OP's real data
- we do not know beforehand if/where the various patterns occur in the file; while OP's example shows `pattern{1,2,3}` on successive lines, I'm going to assume this may not always be the case
- on a line where `-new` is to be appended, we only append to the first match on the line (eg, if line = `pattern2 pattern2` then newline = `pattern2-new pattern2`), otherwise `sub()` could be replaced with `gsub()` to append to all instances on the line
- more than one of the desired 'patterns' could occur on the same line in which case we could see multiple appends on the same line, eg, `pattern1 pattern2 pattern3` would become `pattern1 pattern2-new pattern3-new` and all remaining lines with `pattern2` or `pattern3` would be discarded

One (verbose) `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/pattern1/             { replace2=replace3=1 }
/pattern2/ && remove2  { next }
/pattern2/ && replace2 { sub(/pattern2/,"pattern2-new"); remove2=1 }
/pattern3/ && remove3  { next }
/pattern3/ && replace3 { sub(/pattern3/,"pattern3-new"); remove3=1 }
1
' patterns.txt
```

For OP's sample input this generates:

```
text
text
pattern2
pattern3
text
text
pattern1
pattern2-new
pattern3-new
text
text
```

Running against a couple different sets of data:

```
############ before
text
pattern2
pattern3
text
pattern1
text
pattern2
text
pattern3
pattern2
pattern3
pattern2
pattern3
text

############ after
text
pattern2
pattern3
text
pattern1
text
pattern2-new
text
pattern3-new
text


############ before
text
pattern2
pattern3
text
pattern1 pattern2 pattern3 pattern2 pattern3
text
pattern2
text
pattern3
text

############ after
text
pattern2
pattern3
text
pattern1 pattern2-new pattern3-new pattern2 pattern3
text
text
text
```

Answer (score 0):

With [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), based on `l` flag:

```
$ awk '
    BEGIN{l=1}
    /^pattern1/{print;l=0;print "pattern2-new";print "pattern3-new";next}
    !/^pattern/{l=1}
    l
' file

text
text
pattern2
pattern3
text
text
pattern1
pattern2-new
pattern3-new
text
text
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/pattern1/!{p;b}
       :a;p;n
       :b;/^pattern2$/!ba
       N;/\npattern3$/!{P;s/.*\n//;bb}
       x;/./{x;;n;bb};s/.*/pattern2-new\npattern3-new/;ba' file
```

Turn off implicit printing by setting option `-n`.

If the current line is not `pattern1`,print and then perform no further processing of that line.

Otherwise, enter a loop which will persist until the end of the file.

Print the current line and replace it with the next line.

If the current line does not contain `pattern2`, repeat above.

Otherwise the current line does contain `pattern2`, append the next line.

If the second line does not contains `pattern3`, print/delete the first line and repeat above.

Otherwise, the pattern space contains two lines that contain both `pattern2` and `pattern3`.

Swap to the hold space, if it contains anything, this means the above pattern has been seen before, replace the current pattern space with the next line and repeat above.

Otherwise, replace the hold space with the new patterns and repeat above.